# Altera Quartus - How do I simulate a different Entity

Tags: fpga, vhdl, intel-fpga, quartus-ii

I tested the first entity in my project successfully. Now, when I try to create a Vector Waveform File for my second entity, it only lets me add the pins of my first entity. I did set my new entity which needs to be tested as a "Top Level Entity".

I am using Quartus 9, which uses vector waveform files, since I am working on an old FPGA. When creating the vector waveform file, I have to specify what signals go to which pins. I can't select the pins from my new entity there, any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "it only lets me add the pins of my first entity"? Do you mean you are trying to create a test bench automatically and it does not allow you or what?

Comment: I'm not using a testbench - I'm creating a waveform file to test with. And in the vector waveform file, I have to specify what signals go to which pins. I can't select the pins from my new entity here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that this is not possible. I had to create a new project to test my new entity. And then I had to create another project to combine all my entities together.

Comment: It's up to you whether you do it (maybe you might want some other ideas still?) but you can accept your own answers so they don't show up on the unaswered list.